# the kate editor is missing in ubuntu 20.04 start menu

Tags: kate

ever since upgrading to ubuntu 20.04, i can't find the kate IDE in the ubuntu start menu anymore.

i'd also like to be able to start .php and .js and .json files using kate..

i've searched the web for any clues, but could not find any..

please share any ideas you might have for me in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

The bug [which I submitted in June 2020](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kate/+bug/1884432) is still present even with the latest update of 20.04 LTS released in November 2020 (kate 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1) and still unassigned.

I have found how to reproduce the bug (points 1-5), so also a way to MANUALLY repair it (point 6) every time you save a new session.

1. file ~/.local/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop contains blocks in the following order and everything works as it should (Kate is searchable in the dash and can be pinned to the dash bar):

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   ...
   [Desktop Action Session ...]
   ...
   ```
2. open Kate, new session
3. click menubar Session > Save session (choose name, save)
4. the file ~/.local/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop rewrites itself (as it should) but contains blocks in a wrong order (as it should not):

   ```
   [Desktop Action Session ...]
   ...
   [Desktop Action Session ...]
   ...
   [Desktop Entry]
   ...
   ```
5. suddenly, kate icon moves to the bottom on the dash bar, when clicked by the right mouse button, you can no longer pin it nor find it among the dash applications
6. you have to manually open ~/.local/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop and move the `[Desktop Entry]` block to the beginning of the file

Comment: this worked for me. Gotta love Linux...

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this too atm but a clue that might nudge someone:

Deleting the shortcut to Kate in `~/.local/share/applications/` resolved this issue completely for me (inc. restoring it in favorites etc).

The problem is, the next time you start Kate, it just recreates that file and makes the shortcuts disappear again!

Seems like a conflict but that is as far as I've managed to come so far.

Update: purged Kate using apt, manually deleted the offending shortcuts, reinstalled Kate using Ubuntu Software GUI instead and now this problem is gone?! instead my custom syntax definitions don't work like they used to now but that'd be outside context.

Comment: It does not regenerate when you open/close Kate. It regenerates (at least for me: kate 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1) when you save the session.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround might be to fix the offending shortcut file as described here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kate/+bug/1884432 (comment #6)

Basically, open it the file kate `.desktop` file with a text editor and move the whole section starting `[Desktop Entry]` to the top of the file.

**EDIT: Detailed instructions**

0. Make a backup of the shortcut file `~/.local/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop`
1. Open the shortcut file `~/.local/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop` with a text editor (e.g. `gedit`)
2. Look for the section `[Desktop Entry]`. Section titles are written between brackets `[]`. Example:

```
[Desktop Action Session .....] <-- Start of first section
Exec=...
Name=...

[Desktop Entry] <-- Start of section to move
Actions=Session ....
Categories=Qt;KDE;Utility;TextEditor;
Comment=KDE Advanced Text Editor
Exec=kate -b %U
GenericName=Advanced Text Editor
Icon=kate
InitialPreference=9
MimeType=text/plain;
Name=Kate
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=org.kde.kate
X-DBUS-StartupType=Multi
X-DocPath=kate/index.html
X-KDE-HasTempFileOption=true
```

3. Move the section `[Desktop Entry]` at the top of the file. With the previous example, it would yield:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=Session ....
Categories=Qt;KDE;Utility;TextEditor;
Comment=KDE Advanced Text Editor
Exec=kate -b %U
GenericName=Advanced Text Editor
Icon=kate
InitialPreference=9
MimeType=text/plain;
Name=Kate
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=org.kde.kate
X-DBUS-StartupType=Multi
X-DocPath=kate/index.html
X-KDE-HasTempFileOption=true

[Desktop Action Session .....]
Exec=...
Name=...
```

Comment: This answer is not very clear.  "*move the whole section [Desktop Entry] at the top of the file"* -- what do you mean by this?  Open *what* as a text file?  I suggest that you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1285994/edit) your answer to include instructions. Instructions should be scrubbed of ambiguity and not be left up to interpretation.   Your solution should be clear to others and reproducible by anyone following your instructions.  We should not actually have to visit any link to understand the answer.